# Prove formula of matrix norm $\|A\|$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Let $\|\cdot \|:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the norm defined by $$\|x\|=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|ix_i|, \ x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$ Show that the corresponding matrix norm to vector norm $\|\cdot \|$ can be computed by $$\|A\|=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{i}{j}|a_{i,j}|, \ A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$

We have that $$\|A\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}$$ So we have to write the numerator and the denominator using the given formula, right?

It is :\begin{align*}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}&=\frac{\displaystyle{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\left |i\sum_{i,j}a_{i,j}x_i\right |}}{\|x\|}\leq \frac{\displaystyle{\max_{1\leq i\leq n}i\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|\cdot |x_i|}}{\|x\|} \leq \frac{\displaystyle{\left (\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|\right )\cdot \left (\max_{1\leq i\leq n}i |x_i|\right )}}{\|x\|}\\ & =\frac{\displaystyle{\left (\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|\right )\cdot \|x\|}}{\|x\|}=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{i,j}|a_{i,j}|\end{align*}  How do weget the missing term $\frac{i}{j}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one hand, we have
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}
&=\frac{\max_i\left|i(Ax)_i\right|}{\|x\|}\\
&=\frac{\max_i\left|i\sum_j a_{ij}x_j\right|}{\|x\|}\\
&=\frac{\max_i\left|\frac{i}{j}\sum_j a_{ij}jx_j\right|}{\|x\|}\\
&\le\frac{\max_i\frac{i}{j}\sum_j |a_{ij}|\|x\|}{\|x\|}\\
&=\max_i\frac{i}{j}\sum_j |a_{ij}|.
\end{aligned}
On the other hand, tie occurs in the inequality above when $|x_1|=|2x_2|=\cdots=|nx_n|$ and the sign of each $x_j$ is chosen such that $a_{i_0j}x_j\ge0$ for every $j$ on row $i_0$, where $i_0=\arg\max_i\frac{i}{j}\sum_j |a_{ij}|$. Therefore $\sup_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}=\max_i\frac{i}{j}\sum_j|a_{ij}|$.

If you are familiar with the induced maximum norm $\|B\|_\infty=\sup_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Bx\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}$ and know that it is identical to $\max_i\sum_j|b_{ij}|$, here is a cleaner solution. Let $D=\operatorname{diag}(1,2,\ldots,n)$. Then $\|x\|=\|Dx\|_\infty$ and hence
$$
\|A\|
=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|
=\sup_{\|Dx\|_\infty=1}\|DAx\|_\infty
=\sup_{\|y\|_\infty=1}\|DAD^{-1}y\|_\infty
=\|DAD^{-1}\|_\infty.
$$
It is now evident that the $\frac{i}{j}$ factor comes from $DAD^{-1}$ because $(DAD^{-1})_{ij}=\frac{i}{j}a_{ij}$.

Comment: Could you explain to me why we take this $D$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Because $(x_1,2x_2,\ldots,nx_n)^T=Dx$.

Comment: Ahh ok! Could you explain to me the last inequality, $\sup_{\|y\|_\infty=1}\|DAD^{-1}y\|_\infty=\|DAD^{-1}\|_\infty.$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar That's the definition of the induced supremum norm of $DAD^{-1}$. I supposed that you have encountered this norm before. It is fine if you haven't. The important point here is that $\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|=\sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1}\|Bx\|_\infty$ where $B=DAD^{-1}$. This explains the origin of the factor $\frac{i}{j}$ and also transforms the problem to one that uses the more familiar maximum norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$.

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: I have also an other question : If we consider the Chebyshev-norm $\|x\|_\infty=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}|x_i|$ and want to show that $\|A\|_\infty \max_{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum_{j=1}^n  \left | a_{ij} \right |}$ do we do the same with $D=(1,1, \ldots , 1)$ ? Or do we do something else in this case?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, you do the same thing, but with $D=I$ and $A$ replaced by $DAD^{-1}$. This effectively splits the original problem into two subproblems: (1) to prove that $\|A\|=\|DAD^{-1}\|_\infty$ (which I have shown in the answer), (2) to prove that $\|B\|_\infty:=\sup_{\|x\|_\infty=1}\|Bx\|_\infty$ is equal to $\max_i\sum_i|b_{ij}|$. You may of course prove the original identity in one go, but this identity is actually a combination of two different results.

Comment: But... do we need the first part, that $\|A\|=\|DAD^{-1}\|_\infty$ ? Do we maybe need just to show the second part? Since we have to show that $\|A\|_\infty =\max_{1\leq i\leq n}{\sum_{j=1}^n  \left | a_{ij} \right |}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Of course you need the first part. The question after all is about $\|A\|$ rather than $\|A\|_\infty$.

Comment: I have two questions about the edited part. **Question 1** : At "On the other hand, tie occurs in the inequality...." we want to show that there is a vector $x$ such that the equality holds and that means that the supremum of the left side is equal to the right side? **Question 2** :  How can we prove that $\|B\|_{\infty}=\max_i\sum_j|b_{ij}|$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar (1) Yes. (2) It's basically the same proof, but without the complication of the factor $\frac{i}{j}$:
$$
\frac{\|Bx\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}
=\frac{\max_i\left|\sum_j b_{ij}jx_j\right|}{\|x\|_\infty}
\le\frac{\max_i\sum_j |b_{ij}|\|x\|_\infty}{\|x\|_\infty}
=\max_i\sum_j |b_{ij}|.
$$
Tie occurs when $|x_1|=|x_2|=\cdots=|x_n|=1$ and the sign of $x_j$ is chosen such that $b_{i_0j}x_j\ge0$ for every $j$ on row $i_0$, where $i_0=\arg\max_i\sum_j |b_{ij}|$.

Comment: What do you mean by $i_0=\arg\max_i\sum_j |b_{ij}|$ ? Do you mean the row at which the sum of elements is the maximum?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes. Strictly speaking, $\arg\max...$ is a set of maximisers, but in colloquial usage, it also means any maximiser. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Comment: Ok!! Thanks a lot for all the explanations!! :-)